# Cannot accessing the vm_list and mm_struct from a kernel module

Tags: kernel-module, kvm

I am trying to access the `vm_list` and the `mm_struct` from a kernel module, but for some reason, my output is always null, even though I have up to 3 VMs running.

- In case it matters, the whole thing is running inside a VM because I don't want to mess with the real kernel.

```c
#undef __KERNEL__
#define __KERNEL__

#undef MODULE
#define MODULE


// Linux Kernel/LKM headers: module.h is needed by all modules and kernel.h is needed for KERN_INFO.
#include <linux/module.h>    // included for all kernel modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>   // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>     // included for __init and __exit macros
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/kvm.h>
#include <linux/kvm_host.h>
#include <linux/mm_types.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/async.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

struct list_head *vms_list;
struct mm_struct *mms_struct;
raw_spinlock_t *vm_lock;


int init_module(void)
{
    struct list_head *itr;
    struct kvm* kvm;
    int i;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world!\n");

    vms_list = (struct list_head*)kallsyms_lookup_name("vm_list");
    mms_struct = (struct list_head*)kallsyms_lookup_name("mm_struct");
    vm_lock =(raw_spinlock_t*)kallsyms_lookup_name("kvm_lock");
    if(!mms_struct && !vms_list){
        printk(KERN_INFO "vms_list and mms_struct are %p, %p\n", vms_list, mms_struct);
        return 0;    <--- This line gets executed every time.
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "here 2\n");

    raw_spin_lock(vm_lock);
    list_for_each_entry(kvm, vms_list, vm_list)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "%p\n", kvm);
    }
    raw_spin_unlock(vm_lock);

    itr = 0;
    // printk(KERN_INFO "%p\n", itr);
    return 0;
};

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world!\n");
};
```

References:

- [vm_list](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kvm_host.h#L146) -> [list_head](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/types.h#L185)
- [mm_struct](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L344)

Comment: It's may be just my misunderstanding, but are you trying to enumerate host VMs from inside of the hosted VM? Why would this work?

Comment: No. My setup is like this: One VM emulates to host, inside it I have another 3 VMs. The first VM which emulates the host, runs the code above. The only reason I did this is because I don't want to mess with the kernel structs on a real machine (that holds data I need).

Comment: Have you checked the `/proc/kallsyms` to see that those symbols are actually exported and at what address?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

In short:  VirtualBox (which runs the outer guest), does not support nested virtualization (see [feature request](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032)).
I have found this out by simply doing a `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep vmx` and getting an empty output.

Hope this will someday help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try using qemu nested virtualization on a linux host. (a dream within a dream)

```
      --------------------
 L2  |  VM_1 | VM_2 | ... |
      --------------------
 L1  |   guest hypervisor |
     ---------------------
 L0  |   host hypvevisor  |
      --------------------
```

You need to enable the VMX instructions into the guest hypervisor:

- enable nested virtualization when inserting the kvm module:

  `modprobe kvm_intel nested=1`
- enable the vmx cpu flag when starting qemu in L0

  `qemu .... -cpu qemu64,+vmx -enable-kvm`

Now when you start your VM's from L1, you should be able to see a non-null vm_list.